# Elmah.axd - getting error 404 on both IIS Express and IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

Can anyone suggest why the elmah error page isn't showing up and I get an error 404. I'm using IISExpress. I'm sure I had this working and don't remember making any changes to web.config to stop this from working.

My config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </httpModules>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
<elmah>
   <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 8):

From the look of it, I believe your config is wrong. You are defining `<httpModules />` and `<httpHandlers />` outside the context of `<system.web />`. Also, you'll want to define your handler in `<system.webServer />` for IIS 7+ support. Try this instead:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
            <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>      
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
            <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
            <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
            <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
            <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <elmah>
        <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
    </elmah>
</configuration>
```

Check [this link](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-sp2-sample-web.config) for an example of a valid Web.config for ELMAH 1.2.

Comment: This error is also visible on IIS Express, but it can be addressed by looking at the project properties - Manage Pipeline Mode setting (set to classic). The System.webServer settings are needed for deployment on IIS7 with the Manage Pipeline Mode set to Integrated. For more information, look at this article:  http://www.ozkary.com/2015/12/404-error-axd-http-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you still ignoring the Elmad.axd in the routing? This could be the problem when using MVC.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
```

Comment: Yes, I am ignoring this route.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this helps, but do you have an error page set-up and configured in your web.config?

This is what we have configured:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.htm"></customErrors>
```

There is an accompanying errorpage.htm file in the main directory of our app.

Comment: This answer isn't particularly relevant to ELMAH.